# What are the security issues with JavaScript's Import Maps?

Tags: javascript, security, es6-modules, javascript-security

When I look at [MDN Import Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap), I see a possible breach of security.

I consider this scenario:
someone uses a JS library from any open source git repository which uses an `import`. Now someone comes along and hijacks either your local code or the open source repository. At least he is able to sneak in a little custom import map, which bends the imports to an external malicious source.

Is this scenario feasible and could we do anything about it?

I reckon using an empty `<script type="importmap"></script>`, since there is only one import map allowed per document.

### Edit:

To elaborate more on a possible exploitation scenario:

Consider yourself as a non-security-expert web developer (let's call her Alice), who uses some frontend framework. He downloads some library to his web server and imports it with a `import` command in JS. Now some malicious create (let's call him Bob) hacks Alice's repo and sneakily adds an import map to her HTML code, which bends the local library to an external one. Alice might never ever notice somethings wrong here.

Comment: I think this scenario requires you to have been loading code from an untrusted third party in the first place..?

Comment: A simple [CSP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) could also block code from unwanted sources

Comment: "*he is able to sneak in a little custom import map*" - what do you mean by that? That the attacker is able to modify your HTML and add a `<script type="importmap">…</script>`? That the attacker is able to modify a script that is getting executed and add `document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script'))`? Or something else?

Comment: @Bergi The attack vector is that somehow the attacker can bend the import map in a way that you import unsafe code instead of a safe one. Whether it is through adding an Import map via HTML or JS is not relevant. My prime issue here is that you won't recognize the bending very easily.

Comment: @AKX what if the Import Map bends your internal imports (those that you think are safe) to an external one?

Comment: @yunzen How does this bent import map get on your page? The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#import-map) says "Import maps are currently disallowed once any module loading has started, or once a single import map is loaded. These restrictions might be lifted in future specification revisions." so a malicious module can't change the single import map allowed.

Comment: @yunzen Any attack that hijacks dependencies, whether through import map bending, monkeypatching, or something else, is not easily recognisable.

Comment: @AKX What if there is no import map to begin with? Sneakin' in an import map, when there is none existing might not be too difficult.

Comment: @Bergi You are absolutely right. But why did we introduce these import maps then? Are they really necessary?

Comment: @yunzen You say "might not be too difficult" but _how_ would this malicious actor sneak in an import map? As I can see it, someone would have to sneakily edit the source HTML hosting your script, in which case you're already screwed because they can just as well inject any other script, import maps or not?

Comment: @yunzen Yes, they're absolutely useful. A module specifier is about *what* module to load, the import map tells the browser *where* to find that module (on which server at which path). The "same" module might be served in different locations in different installations/apps/setups; locations that the author of a dependency would not know for example. Sure it might be possible to do static path transformations during a build step, but import maps are a much simpler solution.

Comment: @yunzen Re your edit about Bob hacking Alice's repo, why is "Alice might never ever notice something's wrong here" somehow specific to Bob adding an import map? Alice might never ever notice Bob editing Alice's first-party code either, then, either?

Answer (score 2):

If someone can hijack your local code, they can inject any code in the page already, so they don't need an import map.

If your page is loading code from an external domain which gets compromised, the attacker can also inject any code, and again does not need an import map. Do not load code from domains you don't trust.

Comment: …and use [subresource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) when you load code from domains you don't control (even if you trust them)